# Differences of $1$ or $2$

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of all seven-digit numbers, which start with the digit $1$ and end with the digit $9$, such that the difference of any two adjacent digits is $1$ or $2$. If each place can take $2$ values , after $5$ digits if in each previous place, the difference was of $2$ , what will be the next digits? Also, is there a simpler way of doing this?(My initial method will go wrong since the last digit is known, and I won't get it from my method)

Comment: Is something like $1313579$ allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it up into easier, suggestive subproblems:

1. What if you only have differences by $2$s? For instance, $1357979$ and $1353579$ are among the possibilities. One way of thinking of this is to arrange five UPS and one DOWN, with the caveat that the first difference is UP.
2. What if you have only one difference of $1$? (Can you quickly explain why there are none?)
3. What if you have exactly two differences by $1$? For instance, $1213579$? This is the most annoying of the bunch, but it helps if you can show that the differences will have exactly one +1 and exactly one -1. Then you're arranging PLUSTWOs, one PLUSONE and one MINUSONE.
4. What if you have exactly four differences by $1$? For instance, $1234579$? They must all be increases. So one way of thinking of this is to arrange four ONES and two TWOs.
5. Why do these cover all possible cases?

Comment: Could you tell me the final answer? I don't know where I am going wrong but I am getting a wrong answer. (I think that I am committing a mistake in 3rd case of yours. Thanks.

Comment: @Garvil: I make it $\binom51=5$ in (1), $\binom62=15$ in (4), and a total of $25$ in (3): if you start with a PLUSTWO, there are $\binom52\cdot2=20$ ways to finish, and if you start with the PLUSONE, there are $\binom51=5$ ways.

Comment: That means a total of 45. Which is wrong!

Comment: @Garvil: You didn’t ping me, so I saw your comment only because I happened to check back. What do you think is the correct answer?

Comment: I don't know.Ask mixedmath.